# SoundCloud API: request on /resolve does not return a JSON object

Tags: java, soundcloud

I'm using Unirest in java with a /resolve request to get the ID of a track that a user provides. My code used to work perfectly, then about 1-2 months ago the API returns this: http://hastebin.com/ofidoxuyec.xml, which explains why this happens when I try to parse the response:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at net.masterzach32.swagbot.music.player.SoundCloudAudio.<init>(SoundCloudAudio.java:46)
    at net.masterzach32.swagbot.commands.music.PlayCommand.execute(PlayCommand.kt:91)
    at net.masterzach32.swagbot.EventHandler.onMessageEvent(EventHandler.kt:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher.lambda$null$12(EventDispatcher.java:343)
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.forEach(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:890)
    at sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher.lambda$null$13(EventDispatcher.java:341)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1597)
    at sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher.lambda$null$14(EventDispatcher.java:340)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3606)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at sx.blah.discord.api.events.EventDispatcher.lambda$dispatch$18(EventDispatcher.java:339)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:106)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:139)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode.<init>(JsonNode.java:51)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:95)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:106)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:145)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode.<init>(JsonNode.java:48)
    ... 31 more
```

It happens for any link I provide, even the example track in the API documentation. The weird thing is that the API response code is 200, which means no error right?

The API call works fine in any browser if I just type it in, but not in Java. Any ideas? Thanks!

Code:

(title, author, id, and streamUrl are all fields that are properly declared, and my SoundCloud client ID is valid. I am using the link of the example in the /resolve documentation just for testing)

```
try {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=" + App.prefs.getSCClientId())
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .asJson();

    if(response.getStatus() != 200)
        App.logger.warn("Soundcloud API returned error code " + response.getStatus() + " for the URL " + url);

    JSONObject json = response.getBody().getObject();

    title = json.getString("title");
    author = json.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
    id = json.getInt("id") + "";
    if(!json.getBoolean("streamable"))
        throw new NotStreamableException(getSource(), url);
    else
        streamUrl = json.getString("stream_url");
} catch (UnirestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether there is any error message in the response that you get?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes, and it's saying this [link](http://prntscr.com/dl4t3m)

Comment: What is the error message? Put it in your question : it is very relevant. BTW your link above isn't working, but you shouldn't link to important information: put all relevant information in your question itself.

Comment: The track clearly does exists https://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt there is no error message, the API status code is 200!

Comment: The API status code is irrelevant. Have you looked inside the HTML document that is returned? It has a very clear error message in it.

Comment: API status code means there is no server error. That doesn't mean that your code doesn't error. Primary the API returned **XML not JSON**

Comment: yes, I have. the page says multiple things, such as enable javascript and update your browser, but those don't show up when I render the HTML in a browser, it just says the page cannot be found, which is odd because the track does exist, also @cricket_007 the same error occurs even when I try to retrieve the response as XML

Comment: Actually it returns an HTML page, not XML. It's a general debugging skill: if you have an unexplained error, you investigate all the data that you have to see if it gives you any leads as to the cause of the problem. In this case the HTML page shows "**Your current browser isn't compatible with SoundCloud. Please download one of our supported browsers.**" It looks like the OP is not using the current URL to access this API, but if it is the correct URL, then the request should have a User-Agent header set to some value that is accepted by Sound Cloud.

Comment: I stand corrected. I only briefly looked at the link. Yes (X)HTML cannot be parsed as JSON, which is what the Java stacktrace is saying.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt you had the right idea with setting the User-Agent header. Thats really odd that Soundcloud just requires that all of the sudden. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's odd that not sending a "User-Agent" header doesn't work, because you can make a request without this header: `curl -vvv -H "User-Agent:" "http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=your_client_id"`